Why can't I create more than 1 geo replica for my primary database?
I have a primary database in the Premium service level.

I am trying to create a second geo replica to a different region. The primary is in the East Coast, The first replica is in South Central, and now I'm trying to create a second replica in West 2.
The literature states that I can create up to four replicas for a single primary. (I've seen references to the fact that this requires Premium service level so I've boosted the database into the Premium tier.)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/active-geo-replication-overview?view=azuresql#configuring-secondary-database

Up to four geo-secondaries can be created for a primary. If there's
only one secondary, and it fails, the application is exposed to higher
risk until a new secondary is created. If multiple secondaries exist,
the application remains protected even if one of the secondaries
fails. Additional secondaries can also be used to scale out read-only
workloads.

I've created my first replica and now I'm trying to create the second replica in a different region of course. I'm consistently receiving the same error:

Replication limit reached. The database 'test' cannot have more than 1
replication relationships. (Code: GeoReplicaLimitReached)

Can't have more than one replication relationship? But the literature says I should be able to have up to four?
Here is a more complete snapshot of the database configuration.

Thanks for your advice!

You probably have already enable named read scale out or zone redundancy for the database and is counting that as part of the replication limit.

With Hyperscale, named replicas or high availability replicas may be counting towards the limit of replicas, in addition to geo-replicas.

I added a more comprehensive screenshot of the database configuration to my original question. As far as zone redundancy is concerned, I can see the option. It's set to No and it's disabled. Not sure why mine is different from yours. I don't see any option for Read scale-out. Again, not sure why what I see differs from your sample screenshot. Any idea? Thanks!

Also, why does it show 0 for High Availability Secondary Replicas? I've already created one replica.

I thought you were using the more common flavors of Azure SQL (vCore or DTU models). Since you are using Hyperscale, then named replicas may be counting toward the limit. I updated the answer.

See how many types of replicas you have in use already? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/service-tier-hyperscale-frequently-asked-questions-faq?view=azuresql#what-is-the-scalability-of-a-hyperscale-database-

Thank you! I tore down all those databases (just a test scenario) and rebuilt them using vCore Based - General Purpose. I was able to create two geo replicas in two different regions!

You are welcome. Take in consideration that max database size on vCore is 4 TB and Hyperscale supports 100 TB. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-vcore-single-databases?view=azuresql
